# Why had no one jumped?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, ftl-drive

I'm rewatching the Battlestar Galactica miniseries and I spotted something odd:

> Tigh: Munitions depot confirmed, but we have two problems. One, the
>   Ragnar station is at least three days away at best speed. Two, the
>   entire Cylon fleet is between here and there.
>
> Adama: Specialist.
>
> Specialist: Sir.
>
> Adama: Bring me our position.
>
> Specialist: Yes, sir.
>
> Tigh: You don't want to do this.
>
> Adama: I know I don't.
>
> Tigh: Because any sane man wouldn't. It's been, what, twenty,
>   twenty-two years?
>
> Adama: We trained for this.
>
> Tigh: Training is one thing, but - if we're off in our calculations by
>   even a few degrees, we could end up in the middle of the sun.
>
> Adama: No choice. Colonel Tigh, please plot a hyperlight jump from our
>   position to the orbit of Ragnar.
>
> Tigh: Yes, sir.
>
> Dualla: (in tears) Priority message, sir.
>
> Tigh: Engineering, spin up FTL drives one and two.
>
> Man: Spinning up FTL drives one and two.
>
> Tigh: Lieutenant Gaeta, break up the FTL tables and warm up the
>   computers. We are making a jump.

This gives the impression that no one had done a FTP jump since the original cylon war? Is this right? Why not?

Comment: According to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89475/whats-the-big-deal-with-the-first-ftl-jump-in-the-battlestar-galactica-miniseri?rq=1, it's just the Galactica itself that hasn't used its FTL engines for over 20 years.  So, making your first jump in 20+ years be a high-precision, no-room-for-error jump with untested engines and an untested crew is probably a bad idea.

Comment: That makes sense - I'm going to close as a dupe

Comment: So, "retching" means "re-watching" now?

Comment: @JoeL. - ooo bad typo!